# Is assigning a pointer atomic in Go?

Tags: concurrency, go, atomic

Is assigning a pointer atomic in Go?

Do I need to assign a pointer in a lock? Suppose I just want to assign the pointer to nil, and would like other threads to be able to see it. I know in Java we can use volatile for this, but there is no volatile in Go.

Comment: You might find [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/ueSvaEKgyLY/ZW_74IC4PekJ) interesting.

Comment: You might also find reading the ["Go memory model"](http://golang.org/ref/mem) document amusing--it's what defines the requirements for Go implementations.  AFAIK, it does not tell anything about atomicity of load/store operations of primitive types but only speaks about observable ordering of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only things which are guaranteed to be atomic in go are the operations in [sync.atomic](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/).

So if you want to be certain you'll either need to take a lock, eg [sync.Mutex](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) or use one of the atomic primitives.  I don't recommend using the atomic primitives though as you'll have to use them everywhere you use the pointer and they are difficult to get right.

Using the mutex is OK go style - you could define a function to return the current pointer with locking very easily, eg something like

```
import "sync"

var secretPointer *int
var pointerLock sync.Mutex

func CurrentPointer() *int {
    pointerLock.Lock()
    defer pointerLock.Unlock()
    return secretPointer
}

func SetPointer(p *int) {
    pointerLock.Lock()
    secretPointer = p
    pointerLock.Unlock()
}
```

These functions return a copy of the pointer to their clients which will stay constant even if the master pointer is changed.  This may or may not be acceptable depending on how time critical your requirement is.  It should be enough to avoid any undefined behaviour - the garbage collector will ensure that the pointers remain valid at all times even if the memory pointed to is no longer used by your program.

An alternative approach would be to only do the pointer access from one go routine and use channels to command that go routine into doing things. That would be considered more idiomatic go, but may not suit your application exactly.

**Update**

[Here is an example](http://play.golang.org/p/tvjjkc9QYX) showing how to use `atomic.SetPointer`.  It is rather ugly due to the use of `unsafe.Pointer`.  However `unsafe.Pointer` casts compile to nothing so the runtime cost is small.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

type Struct struct {
    p unsafe.Pointer // some pointer
}

func main() {
    data := 1

    info := Struct{p: unsafe.Pointer(&data)}

    fmt.Printf("info is %d\n", *(*int)(info.p))

    otherData := 2

    atomic.StorePointer(&info.p, unsafe.Pointer(&otherData))

    fmt.Printf("info is %d\n", *(*int)(info.p))

}
```

Comment: I did look at the atomic package, and didn't see a method for atomic storing pointer to a struct. The method StorePointer doesn't look like the right one.                                        func StorePointer(addr *unsafe.Pointer, val unsafe.Pointer)

Comment: Have updated the answer with a `StorePointer` example.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood When using `atomic.StorePointer`, is it necessary to use `atomic.ReadPointer` in order to read it or is a regular non-atomic read okay? The store barrier used in `atomic.StorePointer` should block concurrent reads, so it sounds useless to me using `atomic.ReadPointer` in that case. Is that right?

Comment: Are you sure the first example would work in broader context: the thread doing `SetPointer` would presumably need to populate the pointed-to value before publishing the new pointer value. I didn't see anything in the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) that establishes that the write to `*secretPointer` *happens before* the write to `secretPointer`, from the reader thread's point of view.

Comment: On further meditation: with the mutex the read of `secretPointer` *happens after* the write by virtue of the mutex rules. The write of `*secretPointer` *happens before* the write of `secretPointer` by virtue of intra-goroutine program order. Those are enough to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Since the spec doesn't specify you should assume it is not. Even if it is currently atomic it's possible that it could change without ever violating the spec.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Nick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21451010/1816774), since Go 1.4 there is [`atomic.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value) type. Its `Store(interface)` and `Load() interface` methods take care of the `unsafe.Pointer` conversion.

Simple [example](https://play.golang.org/p/hQCAatrf7oc):

```
package main

import (
    "sync/atomic"
)

type stats struct{}

type myType struct {
    stats atomic.Value
}

func main() {
    var t myType
    
    s := new(stats)
    
    t.stats.Store(s)
    
    s = t.stats.Load().(*stats)
}
```

Or a more extended example from the documentation on the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cbdhlTg_-CT).

Answer (score 3):

Since Go 1.19 [atomic.Pointer](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer) is added into `atomic`

> The sync/atomic package defines new atomic types Bool, Int32, Int64, Uint32, Uint64, Uintptr, and **Pointer**. These types hide the underlying values so that all accesses are forced to use the atomic APIs. Pointer also avoids the need to convert to unsafe.Pointer at call sites. Int64 and Uint64 are automatically aligned to 64-bit boundaries in structs and allocated data, even on 32-bit systems.

[Sample](https://betterprogramming.pub/atomic-pointers-in-go-1-19-cad312f82d5b)

```golang
type ServerConn struct {
    Connection net.Conn
    ID string
}

func ShowConnection(p *atomic.Pointer[ServerConn]) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(p, p.Load())
    }
}
func main() {
    c := make(chan bool)
    p := atomic.Pointer[ServerConn]{}
    s := ServerConn{ID: "first_conn"}
    p.Store(&s)
    go ShowConnection(&p)
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(13 * time.Second)
            newConn := ServerConn{ID: "new_conn"}
            p.Swap(&newConn)
        }
    }()
    <-c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that atomicity has nothing to do with "I just want to assign the pointer to nil, and would like other threads to be able to see it". The latter property is called visibility.

The answer to the former, as of right now is yes, assigning (loading/storing) a pointer is atomic in Golang, this lies in the updated [Go memory model](https://go.dev/ref/mem)

> Otherwise, a read r of a memory location x that is not larger than a machine word must observe some write w such that r does not happen before w and there is no write w' such that w happens before w' and w' happens before r. That is, each read must observe a value written by a preceding or concurrent write.

Regarding visibility, the question does not have enough information to be answered concretely. If you merely want to know if you can dereference the pointer safely, then a plain load/store would be enough. However, the most likely cases are that you want to communicate some information based on the nullness of the pointer. This requires you using `sync/atomic`, which provides synchronisation capabilities.

Comment: Depending what the pointer is pointing at, you often do need release/acquire synchronization to deref one safely, not just atomicity.  (plain asm load/store is like C++ `std::memory_order_relaxed`, except on ISAs like x86 where the hardware memory model is more strongly ordered.)

Comment: Yes, by safely here I mean merely not getting a nil pointer exception, such as when you have an existing cache and want to throw it away to save memory. I agree that in the vast majority of the cases acquire/release semantics is the desired one, though.