# How to check if nested pointers access/methods are invalid at runtime

Tags: pointers, go

Let's say I have a Go struct that looks something like this (please pardon syntax for the sake of explanation):

```
type Foo struct {
    MyBar *Bar
}

type Bar struct {
    value int
}

func (b* Bar) Bark() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello I'm a bar with value: %v", b.value)
}
```

Now, let's say that this `Foo` struct is stored in memory on a process, and it takes some time for the `MyBar` field to be populated. As in, it is `nil` for sometime. Is there any way that I can check if its save to access the `Bark()` method at run time without manually doing `nil` checks?

For example, something like:

```
// Early on, this happens:
f := &Foo{}
.
.
.
.
// And later, I wanna see if its safe to do:
if isSafe(b.MyBar) {
   b.MyBar.Bar()
}
```

The reason I ask this is for deeply nested pointers, this can become pretty painful. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the measure of safety is whether or not the value is `nil`, then the safety check *is* a `nil` check.

Comment: "Foo struct is stored in memory on a process, and it takes some time for the MyBar field to be populated" - does this mean that does this mean it is being updated concurrently (goroutine)? If so the situation is a bit more complicated and you should not assume the pointer update will be atomic (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447463/is-assigning-a-pointer-atomic-in-golang))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no shortcut for deep checking a struct for nil pointers. Your `isSafe` is essentially a nil check:

```
if b.MyBar!=nil {
  b.MyBar.Bark()
}
```

Alternatively, you can also check for nil receiver in the method:

```
func (b* Bar) Bark() {
    if b!=nil {
       fmt.Printf("Hello I'm a bar with value: %v", b.value)
    }
}
```

This last usage may hide bugs in your program, though, because it will run without panicking even when the receiver is not supposed to be nil.