# what is the best way to synchronize access to a map, while usage is only reading from the map, and replacing the map (no write of new entries)

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, atomic, goroutine

I am implementing a mechanism in which I have a map that is only read by multiple go routines (`entry = myMap["b"]`), or entirely replaced, by a single go routine (`myMap = myNewMap`).

According to this well answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447463/is-assigning-a-pointer-atomic-in-go), and go documentation, replacement of a pointer is not atomic and can lead to a race when there is concurrent access.

See this example, which doesn't pass `go run -race`

```
package main

func main() {
    var myMap map[string]string
    go func() {
        myMap = make(map[string]string)
    }()
    if myMap != nil {
        myString := myMap["21"]
        myString = myString // won't compile without usage of myString
    }
}
```

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x00c00019a000 by goroutine 6:
  main.main.func1()
      mic.go:6 +0x3a

Previous read at 0x00c00019a000 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      mic.go:8 +0xcf

Goroutine 6 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      mic.go:5 +0xc5
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

I am looking for a solution which won't require mutex/locks (this is the motivation for the design that doesn't add new entries)

I implemented the following solution using `sync/atomic.Pointer` , which passes `go run -race`

```
package main

import "sync/atomic"

func main() {
    atomicMapPointer := atomic.Pointer[map[string]string]{}

    go func() {
        newMap := make(map[string]string)
        atomicMapPointer.Store(&newMap)
    }()
    if atomicMapPointer.Load() != nil {
        theMap := *atomicMapPointer.Load()
        myString := theMap["21"]
        myString = myString // won't compile without usage of myString
    }
}
```

1. I am wondering if it is the correct solution or something else and more simple can be done
2. a map in go is in practice a pointer, but when using [`atomic.Pointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Pointer) , it actually make it a pointer to a map (so pointer to pointer) and then usage requires dereference. Should I even use atomic.Pointer? maybe [`atomic.Value`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#Value)  is more suitable?
3. Should I use `atomicMapPointer.Load()`  in every access or can I save it aside to a var and use the var? what will when I read from the saved var, how the race is solved then?

Comment: Sounds like your usage pattern is a good fit for RCU (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update).  In a garbage-collected language, deallocation is a non-problem, so yeah, just an atomic pointer / reference that you load every time and then use.  That should be cheap, especially if Go lets you just ask for acquire semantics instead of seq_cst.

Comment: You might also try a mutex version and benchmark it against the atomic one within your application. A mutex operation is tens of machine cycles, and while it may be a bottleneck in your program, it's also quite possible you're overcomplicating things for no real gain.

Comment: have you tried using something like type SafeMap struct {
 mu sync.RWMutex
 m  map[string]string
}
which gives you cuncurrent read and one write at same time

Comment: Think about the constraints of your problem. If you are going to swap out the map, then you simply _must_ guard any access to that map for when it is swapped.  You can either use a mutex (which is probably fine until you can prove it’s not) or an atomic.Value which has an example in the docs.